# graphite web, how do you add a function? Button missing from internet?

Tags: graphite

I am using graphite web version 1.1.5.  I cannot find any button to use the functions.  [The documentation says](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dashboard.html)

> An Apply Function menu button, which allows functions to be applied to
>   the currently-selected item in the metrics list...An Apply Function
>   menu button, which allows functions to be applied to the
>   currently-selected item in the metrics list

If you look at the attached screen print I don't see any such button.  Another version of the documentation says to click an item in the metric tree.  No button there either.

So how do you apply a function?  Where's the menu item to allow that.

I tried Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function by going to `Graph Data > select the metric > Apply function`

[image]